# Use mod_rewrite (.htaccess) to restrict URIs for different subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a website on an Apache server with multiple domains and subdomains.  I want to continue redirecting requests to most domains to the preferred domain, but now I also want to separate out a couple URIs to require use of new subdomains as described below.

We have resources on the website under `/media`, and `/api` that I want to "move" off `www.domain.com` and onto `static.domain.com` and `api.domain.com`.  (The primary reason is to eliminate cookie traffic for static resources.)  The actual paths on the web server will not change.

To complicate things, I want to continue to allow access to the primary domain to `/media`, but for anything under `/api`, which is brand new, I only want to allow access via `api.domain.com`.  Everything else should return a 404.

EDIT:

Based on Jon's answer below, I added the following block to restrict the `api` subdomain to URIs containing `/api/`.

```
#Restrict api subdomain to /api
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

However, I cannot seem to do the opposite and prevent all other subdomains from accessing the `/api/` URI.  The following block seems to have no effect.

```
#Disallow /api from any domain that doesn't start with 'api.'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Help is appreciated in getting this block fixed.

EDIT 2:

The current ModRewrite code is in .htaccess in the documentroot for the server.  There are no other .htaccess files and no ModRewrite config in httpd.conf.  I suspect my second issue above (disallowing /api) lies in the fact that everything is ultimately routed to CodeIgniter via index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #For stats tracking:
    RewriteRule ^server-status - [L]

    #Send old canada URI requests to canada server:
    RewriteRule ^canada(.*)$ http://canada.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

    #Don't allow access via server01 name:
    RewriteRule ^server01\.domain\.com(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

    #Restrict api subdomain to /api:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule !^api/.*$ - [R=404,L]

    #Make http://domain.com requests go to http://www.domain.com:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.us
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.net
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #Don't allow access by IP:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #Perform rewrite for CSS file versioning:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/style/([0-9]*)/(.*).css$
    RewriteRule ^style/.*/(.*)$ style/$1

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you set the documentroot to that `/api` & `/media` folders, or do you have them set to the current documentroot for some reason? (I'd normally define a seperate vhost & separate root, _especially_ for something like `static`...), which makes the redirect a bit simpler.

Comment: @Wrikken, hindsight is 20/20. Alas, there is a single `DocumentRoot` and that won't be changing anytime soon.

Comment: Can you provide your full .htaccess here in the question. Is there any other .htaccess as well in your system?

Comment: @anubhava - done.  Also see my comment about CodeIgniter - I suspect that may be a culprit.

Comment: Thanks I checked, I don't see `#Disallow /api from any domain that doesn't start with 'api.'` rule in your .htaccess? Have you tried add that rule right at the top?

Comment: @anubhava you are correct, this is on a live system so I didn't leave it in there when it didn't work.  It was immediately below the "#Restrict" block.

Answer (score 1):

Add above the rules you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ http://static.domain.com/media/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://api.domain.com/api/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It seems so simple when I see it in front of me. :)  I think I need to make some minor modifications around something that wasn't clear in my question.. Followup shortly...

Comment: @MikeS. where in your htaccess file are you adding the `RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ - [R=404,L]` rule?

Comment: I just updated the .htaccess above to show where it restricts /api to the api subdomain.  I had previously tested the other code (disallow /api from non-api domain) directly below that..

Comment: @MikeS. why is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` there?

Comment: Existing files should be served up as requested. Everything else (!-f) gets handled by CodeIgnter = index.php